# Как в java присвоить переменной типа byte отрицательное значение в двоичном представлении?

Tags: java

```
public class SoloPractice5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte a = 0b01111111;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

В консоль выдаёт: 127

Как записать -127? Т.е. записать то можно так "-0b01111111", но меня интересует, где в реальности хранится знак минус, в каком бите? Какую комбинацию из восьми битов нужно записать в переменную байт, чтобы в консоли получить -127?

Comment: *в каком бите* - в первом

Comment: byte a = 0bхххххххх(вот вместо х'ов какие записать, чтобы в консоли вывело -127?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Java используется дополнение единицей, старший бит это знаковый бит, вы можете изменить его на единицу, или сделать инвертирование, типа

~0b01111111 + 1

Тоесть отрицательное представление числа это полностью инвертированные биты исходного числа + 1, единицу надо добавлять потому что один бит исхолго числа уходит в представление знака

Comment: int a = 0b00000000000000000000000001111111;//127
int b = 0b11111111111111111111111110000001;-127
Это для типа int, а для byte как будет выглядеть?

Comment: Точно так же только с более маленькой размерностью числа

Comment: byte a = 0b10000001;//Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte

Comment: Ну, естесно, все правильно, java автоматически большие числа преобразует до int, у напишите так

`byte b = (byte) 0b10000001`

Comment: Ого, теперь все правильно работает! Огромная благодарность! :)

Comment: Да не за что, рад был помочь )

Answer (score 3):

По крайней мере большинство современных процессоров (если не все) представляют отрицательные числа с помощью метода [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), используя первый бит для обозначения знака числа (0 - положительное, 1 - отрицательное). Этот метод состоит в следующем: все биты в значении инвертируются, после чего к значению прибваляется единица. Это может звучать непонятно, но с примером обычно приходит базовое понимание, что отсчет просто ведется "сверху вниз":

```
0b0111 = 111 = 7, первый бит равен нулю = число положительное
0b1111 = ~1111 + 1 = 0000 + 1 = 0001 = 1, т.е. 1111 соответствует минус одному
0b1110 = ~1110 + 1 = 0001 + 1 = 0010 = 2 => -2
0b1101 = ~1101 + 1 = 0010 + 1 = 0011 = 3 => -3
...
0b1000 = ~1000 + 1 = 0111 + 1 = 1000 = 8 => -8
```

Java, конечно, использует для простоты именно эту конвенцию, поэтому для получения числа `минус N` необходимо

- перевести N в двоичный вид
- применить метод two's complement (он обратен сам себе) к полученному значению

Чаще всего эти операции без проблем получается совершить в уме. Для -127:

```
127 = 0b01111111
complement(127) = ~0b01111111 + 1 = 0b10000000 + 1 = 0b10000001
```

Что и было продемонстрировано в соседнем ответе. Здесь же, кстати, можно увидеть, что диапазон отрицательных чисел на единицу больше - это происходит из-за того, что ноль занимает одно место в диапазоне положительных чисел.